# Socket hang up when using axios.get, but not when using https.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, axios, node-https

To the best of my knowledge, I am doing the same thing using 2 different approaches:

```
const https = require("https");
const axios = require("axios");

let httpsAgent = new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: false});

axios.get(`https://${hostname}:${port}${path}`, {httpsAgent})
    .then((data) => { console.log("axios success: " + data.substr(0, 100)); })
    .catch((error) => { console.log("axios error: " + error); });

let data = "";
https.get({ hostname, path, port, agent: httpsAgent },
    (response) => {
        response.on("data", (chunk) => { data += chunk; });
        response.on("end", () => { console.log("https success: " + data.substr(0, 100)); });
    })
    .on("error", (error) => { console.log("https error: " + error); });
```

When I run this code, i get 2 different outcomes:

```
PS C:\Users\me> .\node\node.exe .\generate-test-data.js
axios error: Error: socket hang up
https success: [{"cool":"data"...
```

What is going on here?  I have a feeling it has to do with asynchronicity, but not quite sure how...  Can somebody give me a hint as to how/why these 2 behaviors are different?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ARGH!

After digging around in the axios source, I found this:

```
if (!proxy) {
  var proxyEnv = protocol.slice(0, -1) + '_proxy';
  var proxyUrl = process.env[proxyEnv] || process.env[proxyEnv.toUpperCase()];
  if (proxyUrl) {
    var parsedProxyUrl = url.parse(proxyUrl);
    proxy = {
      host: parsedProxyUrl.hostname,
      port: parsedProxyUrl.port
    };

    if (parsedProxyUrl.auth) {
      var proxyUrlAuth = parsedProxyUrl.auth.split(':');
      proxy.auth = {
        username: proxyUrlAuth[0],
        password: proxyUrlAuth[1]
      };
    }
  }
}
```

But nothing for `no_proxy`.  Seems there is a [feature request for this](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/434)...  In the meantime, i will just have to:

```
    delete process.env['http_proxy'];
    delete process.env['HTTP_PROXY'];
    delete process.env['https_proxy'];
    delete process.env['HTTPS_PROXY'];
```

Comment: Man I needed this

Comment: This is a life saver :)

Comment: do I need to include this before each call?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I put this before each axios call and always get the socket hang up error :/

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the lead ( and the digging :) ), the code that you identified is from http module, and around it; there is clue that this problem can be addressed by two other approaches

1. set up proxy = false in axios config, something like -

```
https.get({ hostname, path, port, proxy:false, agent: httpsAgent },
```

2. set up no proxy env variable for target host

```
$export NO_PROXY=<host name of targeted URL>
```

I tried both of above approaches and it did address the issue. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was the answer for me today. In my situation, I had proxy configuration via a defined httpsAgent (what I wanted) and this was interacting badly with an inadvertent `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable setting. This produced the "socket hang up" error in Axios. The fix was the explicit `proxy:false` setting as per this answer.