# how to fix the error (is not a function) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello I am learning react and currently I stumble on an error message:
(TypeError: newsData.map is not a function)
in my browser when I run my code. Vs code does not notify me of an error only my browser displays it (I use crome)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation";
import Logo from "../components/Logo";
import axios from "axios";
import Article from "../components/Article";

const News = () => {
  const [newsData, setNewsData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getNews();
  }, []);
  const getNews = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/articles")
      .then((res) => setNewsData(res));
  };
  return (
    <div className="news-container">
      <Navigation />
      <Logo />
      <h1>News</h1>

      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nom" />
        <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
      </form>
      <ul>
        {newsData.map((article) => (
          <Article />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default News;
```

Comment: Could you confirm what kind of value `newsData` holds may be include a small example.

Comment: Is your api responding with an array of data? Have you tried consoling it? newsData.map is not a function is shown when the response is not an array

Comment: are you getting array type data in `res`  when you make axios call?

Comment: `res` probably isn't an array. Use `console.debug(res)` to see what's in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios GET request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437176/axios-get-request-not-working)

Comment: yes thank you i resolved the problem

Answer (score 2):

This means that `newsData` is not an array. Considering that you initialized it as an empty array (`const [newsData, setNewsData] = useState([]);`) I think that your problem is here:

```
setNewsData(res)
```

`res` is not an array.

To solve this you should set `newsData` as:

```
setNewsData(res.data)
```

Comment: @PhilippeTankoano Happy to ear that. Have a nice coding =)